# How do I level the edge of concrete foundation?

Tags: concrete, flooring, subfloor

I replaced some engineered hardwood flooring recently and we noticed that it was slanted because towards the edge of the house, the concrete subfloor (no underlayment) is slanted there. What can I do to re-level the underlayment or just lift up the edge? It's only about a board and a half (~10 inches) and creates about a 1/5" difference. Can I use a floor patch product and skim it flat?

Comment: A picture always helps

Answer (score 2):

Grind it down if it's high, fill it in if it's low.

Self-levelling compound might be a better choice than "floor patch" (whatever that may be) if the rest of the floor is level. If the rest of the floor is not level a product that stays put and works well in thin sections such as thinset mortar may work better.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with the mess of leveling compound, you may be able to get some cheap sheet vinyl flooring and basically build up a wedge—stack layers of varing widths strips.

Answer (score 1):

If the concrete isn't sealed (spray some water on it and wait a couple minutes to see if it soaks into the concrete), then you want a Portland cement based product than can be transitioned to zero thickness. I'm thinking of Henry 547 or 549.

If the concrete is sealed, then adhesion of any "floor patch" product will be a problem. You can use an angle grinder and a diamond wheel if you're desperate to use some kind of adhesive patching product. There also exist chemical strippers like xylene that will work (and stink up your whole house). Retest with water after treatment to verify that the concrete is ready.

In the case of sealed concrete, you might want to shim instead. I would get wood shims somewhat close with a table saw and use a flap disc on an angle grinder for any fine tuning.